# is ConnectionClosedByClient exception from pika a problem

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, pika

I recently upgraded to a newer version of pika and these logs started showing up where they have not been there before:

`User-initiated close: result=BlockingConnection__OnClosedArgs(connection=<SelectConnection CLOSED transport=None params=<URLParameters host=rabbitmq port=xxxxx virtual_host=xxxxx ssl=False>>, error=ConnectionClosedByClient: (200) 'Normal shutdown')`

`AMQP stack terminated, failed to connect, or aborted: opened=True, error-arg=None; pending-error=ConnectionClosedByClient: (200) 'Normal shutdown'`

`Stack terminated due to ConnectionClosedByClient: (200) 'Normal shutdown'`

I have looked over my changes but all I was doing before these logs showed up was to upgrade my django project libraries

No changes in logic have taken place
It is confusing because according to documentation this exception, ConnectionClosedByClient, is raised when "Connection was closed at request of Pika client." which is the normal behaviour?
Also it says Normal Shutdown

So am i safe to assume this is just a new log that is cluttering my logs and isn't an actual error because all my rabbitMQ and logs are all good and they are behaving properly as well

If it is the case that it is just new logs and this exception needs to be handled for it to not appear in logs, any tips on how to do that safely as well